# marker show if marker inside polygon and invisible if marker outside polygon in android

Tags: android, google-maps

My Question is how to find lat long inside the polygon or not i have 1000 markers in my database , when app started then all markers visible and when we draw shape and apply then only marker inside the polygon show ,,this is very important for me please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, take your time, write a question which is readable and show your effort.

Comment: i am just saying that i have 1000 lat-long in Array-list on entire Google map , if i am draw a polygon on map using drawing then those marker visible whose inside the polygon and others invisible ....@Steve benett

Comment: We understand what you want, but what have to tried yourself already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) have a function in PolyUtil called containsLocation() wich can test if a location is inside a passed polygon.

A dummy approach is to test your markers and draw only those inside the polygon.

Comment: this is not working well .any other methods please help me....

Comment: This working well but a small bit bug i will caught it and solve the error thanks @ Lmoro